# Where is the unlock full access in filemanager on Aquaris Ubuntutouch?

Tags: permissions, root, filemanager, aquaris

I use the File Manager version 0.4.386 and I don't find the "unlock full access" button.

It is not in the field with with new file and properties. I don't know why. If somebody could help me that would be great.

I have found this in launchpad but I really don't see the button on my phone.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-filemanager-app/+bug/1386254

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Developer Mode first in order to see this menu entry.

To enable Developer Mode:

1. System Settings
2. About this phone
3. Developer mode (last point on this page)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I found it :it's developer mode and you have to add an unlock screen with a pin or a passphrase.